# parallelize optimization tests when building python from source

Tags: python

When compiling Python from source, there is a popular option to `--enable-optimizations` which runs a bunch of tests and then adds optimizations to the compiled runtime.

Is it possible to parallelize the running of the tests given multiple cores on the system, à la `make -j8` given 8 cores?